# Is iCloud only meant for UIDocument and CoreData(How to Take Back up of any folder with its data on iCloud)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, backup, icloud

I read the apple documentation and some other links and found there are examples of using iCloud with only either UIDocument or Core Data.

I am having a folder created in documents directory named "backUPFolder" and it contains some images and other files in it.

I want to ask , if it is possible to move this backUPFolder in iCloud with all the data exist in this folder as it is.

If yes it is possible please provide me some useful link or suggest an approach which I can follow.

My requirement is to take a back up of my data on iCloud.

Please please help me.
I am stuck here.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also only seen the UIDocument and Core Data examples. What comes to mind is to transform your pics and docs into Core Data blobs and store them with core data anyway. This could also be very efficient.

Alternatively, you could check out the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#ios)s.

Answer (score 0):

If your folder in the Documents or Library folder of your application, it will be backed up to iCloud automatically assuming the user has iCloud enabled (and that you haven't explicitly flagged the file as `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey`).

Any manual interaction with iCloud as a developer is typically to share files explicitly between installations of your app. If your requirement is just to back up data, you don't need to do anything besides store the folder in Documents.

Comment: Also, as an aside, the other way to use iCloud besides UIDocument and CoreData is with `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` which allows you to store key-value pairs in iCloud.